# How to set an action for FAB (AngularDart 5, Dart 2)

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-dart, floating-action-button

I’m trying to work with [Material FAB Menu](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/master/example/material_menu_example/lib/material_fab_menu_demo.dart).

❔ How can I execute a **method** when I click an item of this menu?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MenuItem class has an optional property called action. That accepts a function that will get called when the menu is clicked.

```
new MenuItem('item1-1', tooltip: 'your tooltip', action: () => print('I was clicked')),
```

Comment: OK, but, how can I execute a **method**? For example, how can I execute a command that reads some values from the HTML, does some calculations and puts the result in a `<div>` element? Thanks!

Comment: The above is executing a method print. The method can be anything in the angular controller. () => executeMyFancyMethod(); As for how to interact with the DOM in an angular Controller please ask a separate question as that can be more involved.

Comment: I understand, thank you! I will ask a separate question.